# "C'est pour" or "Il est pour" followed by an adverbial phrase?

Tags: démonstratifs

J'ai du gateau.  C'est pour le dessert.  Il est pour le dessert. Which is correct?

The way I understand this is that "pour le dessert" is a prepositional phrase functioning as an adverbial phrase.  When you have an adverbial phrase with "être" and you are referring specifically to something which has been mentioned you use "il est", "elle est", etc.  As an example we have: Où est le livre.  "Il est sous la chaise." and not "C'est sous la chaise."

Here the specific referent is "du gâteau" and I would think that you use "Il est pour le dessert" and not "C'est" and yet "C'est pour le dessert" seems to be the correct response.   Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

The following deductions stem from an examination of real usage as I remember it.

« Ce » (C') is used when the category involved is what is being characterised. The personal pronoun is used when the meaning indicates a characterisation that is specific.  Sometimes people might use "ce" instead of "il", "elle", etc.

- Le professeur est arrivé. C'est une femme. (*On ne dit pas « Elle est … ».*) _ **category**
- Le professeur est arrivé. Elle sera la seule femme à être professeur dans l'école. _ **specific case**

- J'ai du gâteau ; il est d'hier mais il est encore frais.(*On ne dit pas « c'est … ».*) _ **no category**
- J'ai du gâteau ; c'est un reste d'hier mais il est encore frais. _ **category** then  **specific case**
- J'ai du gâteau ; ce n'est pas de la très bonne pâtisserie, il faudra s'en satisfaire. (*On ne dit pas « il n'est … »*) _ **category**

- J'ai du gâteau ; il n'est pas très bon, mais c'est tout ce que l'on a. _ **specific case**
- J'ai du gâteau ; ce n'est pas du très bon gâteau, mais c'est tout ce que l'on a. _ **category**

- J'ai du gâteau ; il est pour le dessert. _ **specific case**
- J'ai du gâteau ; il est pour ce midi. J'ai  de la tarte aussi mais elle est pour ce soir. _ **specific case**

- J'ai du flan ; il est pour le dessert. _ **specific case**
- J'ai du flan ; ce n'est pas très bon pour un dessert, je sais. _ **category** (never "il")

- J'ai du vin blanc doux ; il est pour le dessert. _ **specific case**
- J'ai du vin blanc sec ; ce n'est pas bien bon pour les desserts. _ **categoric**
- J'ai du vin blanc sec mais il n'est pas trop sec pour les desserts. _ **specific case**

- Où est le livre ? Il est sous la chaise. _ **specific case**
- Qu'est-ce que le livre ? C'est un moyen de communication. _ **category**